# how to show items in a row wise (i.e 5 items per rows)

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

i have a  to show tags onto my view page from controller. I would like to show 5 tags per row ,currently with my below code its showing 1 tag per row. please help me how to do this?

```
 $query = $this->tagsmodel->fetch_all_tags($postnumbers, $offset);
  if (is_array($query))
     {
        foreach ($query as $row) 
         {
            $content = substr(strip_tags($row->tags_name), 0, 180); 
            echo '<div class="parent" id='.$row->tags_id.'>';
            echo '<a class="tagsbtn" href="" >'.$content.'</a>';
            echo '</div>';
         }
     }
```

Currently i am getting output like this
[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do but `display: inline-block` or `float: left` on the `div` elements should help.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i updated my question please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with using css

```
.main {
    width : 400px;
}    
.main .parent{
    float : left;
    margin-right : 10px;
}
```

Adjust the width as per you will get 5 tags in row.

```
 echo "<div class='main'>";
 foreach ($query as $row) 
 {
            $content = substr(strip_tags($row->tags_name), 0, 180); 
            echo '<div class="parent" id='.$row->tags_id.'>';
            echo '<a class="tagsbtn" href="" >'.$content.'</a>';
            echo '</div>';
         }
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: The `No More Posts` div is comming up , and tags div is show same as before

Comment: So you can add another div for tags. and you can apply same css for that div also.

Comment: Please check i have edited my question. There is a global div with class main for all tags

Comment: Still small problem , its showing output like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ny95.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29983/discussion-between-pathik-gandhi-and-ashutosh)

Answer (score 1):

> `$count=0;
>
>       $query = $this->tagsmodel->fetch_all_tags($postnumbers, $offset);
>
>       if (is_array($query))
>
>        {
>
>           foreach ($query as $row)
>
>            {
>
>               $count++;
>
>               $content = substr(strip_tags($row->tags_name), 0, 180);
>
>               echo '<div class="parent" style='float:left;' id='.$row->tags_id.'>';
>
>               echo '<a class="tagsbtn" href="" >'.$content.'</a>';
>
>               echo '</div>';
>               if($count%5==0)  {
>
>               echo "<div style='clear:both'></div>";
>
>                 }
>
>            }
>
>        }`

so now it will display 5 divs per row

Answer (score 0):

Try to set floating for your div `style="float: left;"`:

```
foreach ($query as $row) 
         {
            $content = substr(strip_tags($row->tags_name), 0, 180); 
            echo '<div class="parent" id='.$row->tags_id.' style="float: left;">';
            echo '<a class="tagsbtn" href="" >'.$content.'</a>';
            echo '</div>';
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kasyx solution but you won't be able to control the number of tags displayed on each row. By default, it will fill your div and break to a new line each time the width of displayed tags will be to large.

Use a counter in the loop to control the exact number of tags displayed. You may need to set a fixed width for your div and/or play with the overflow.

Your DOM should looks like

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="rowdiv">
        <div class="parent"><a ... >foo</a></div>
        <div class="parent"><a ... >bar</a></div>
        ...
    </div>
```

and the css properties :

```
.parent { float : left, ...} .rowdiv{ clear : both, ...}
```

The only thing you have to do is to use modulo in your loop and create a new "rowdiv" each 5 iteration.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($query as $row) 
{
    $content = substr(strip_tags($row->tags_name), 0, 180); 
    echo '<li id="'.$row->tags_id.'">';
    echo '<a class="tagsbtn" href="#">'.$content.'</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

**CSS**

```
ul {style-list-type:none}
ul li {display:block;float:left
ul li:nth-child(5n+1) {clear:left}
```

**Update**

This will allow your tag to have dynamic width

**New Working Example**
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQDpY/1/)